# Can you set up Visual Studio to deploy to a Virtual Machine?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, deployment, virtual-machine

I have a virtual machine running windows 2003 server. It is on a separate machine on the network to reserve computer resources on my dev machine. Is it possible to configure visual studio 2008 so when I click "deploy" it will deploy the solution to the virtual machine instead of my development machine?

### Edit

I should note that I am deploying these solution(s) to a sharepoint server

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From Visual Studio's point of view, there is no difference between a virtual machine and a physical machine. If the machine is accessible over the network, you can deploy to it as you would to any other machine.

Answer (score 0):

If you're attempting to publish a website, you can certainly do that.  Is this a web or Windows application?

Comment: It is a web application. I am deploying web parts to a sharepoint server.

Comment: Ah, I see.  SharePoint is an entirely different beast.  I'm starting a new job where I'll be learning it, but at this point I'm unable to assist.

Answer (score 0):

If the network can see your virtual machine then you can deploy to that machine just like any other.